# Is it possible to programatically find out what process is locking a file across a network

Tags: windows, networking, locking

I have a file on a Windows 2003 server which is locked by a process running on another Windows 2003 server.  Is it possible to find out which process on which machine is locking this resource.  I don't mind which language I use to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx

> **PsFile**
>
> The "net file" command shows you a
>   list of the files that other computers
>   have opened on the system upon which
>   you execute the command, however it
>   truncates long path names and doesn't
>   let you see that information for
>   remote systems. PsFile is a
>   command-line utility that shows a list
>   of files on a system that are opened
>   remotely, and it also allows you to
>   close opened files either by name or
>   by a file identifier.
>
> ...
>
> **How it Works**
>
> PsFile uses the NET API, which is documented in the Platform SDK.