# Force close files that are in use when the script runs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have following script that take files older than specified day and saves them as archive in a different folder. The script works fine with most of the files but for some files it gives this error and doesn’t include those file in the archive.

```
Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At C:\SRS\SRSLogArchieveScript.ps1:49 char:13
+             Move-Item <<<<  $item.FullName $destPathController -force;
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\SRS\Controll...apter0611-1.log:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

However I am using `-force` with `-move item` but it still have this issue. Is there a way I can actually force close all the files in use to make sure all files are included as a part of archive.

```
try
{
foreach( $item in (Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $archiveTillDate }) )
{
$item.FullName;
Move-Item $item.FullName $destPath -force;
}
}
catch
{
$_.Exception.Message;
}
Finally
{
#Executing Zip Command to Archieve:
& $pathTo7ZipExe $arguments;

#Delete temporary log archieve directory
Remove-Item $logArchieve -recurse;

}
```

Comment: You could use [Handle.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241178/command-line-tool-for-finding-out-who-is-locking-a-file) to identify the process that is using the file. Then you can kill the process. And you mean to overwrite the file _while it's locked_, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This behavior is by design. Consider that the original application keeping an open file tries to write into it. If you have "stolen" the underlying file, what'll happen? Anything from a crash to unexpected behavior. To prevent such a thing, all modern OS prevent such an operation from non-priviledged users.

That being said, you could use a tool like [Sysinternals'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) `Handle.exe` to check if a file has got open a handle. The same tool can close handles if you have sufficient permissions.

Another a solution would be to try and [open the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/503046) with read-write access. This would allow you to filter out files that are reserved - assuming no process is going to open the file just after you release your own lock. The only way to be sure is to copy the file contents into archive location whlist you got the exclusive write lock and finally deleting the file.

Comment: This is a Windows exclusive "feature", and is an actual cause for various forms of system corruption. This is definitely not how it's done in "Modern OS" - Linux handles file locking differently.

Comment: @Argo I fail to see why discussing file locking on non-Windows system is relevant for a Powershell question *posted three years ago.* Please improve your comment by adding references to sources that back up claims of system corruption and how the locking works in Linux. As of now, it's just hearsay.

Comment: It doesn't matter how old your false assertion is. What matters is it's wrong, and I would like to see it fixed as per community guidelines. As for file locking, you can start looking up implementation details here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Comment: "Improper error-handling in an application program can lead to a scenario where a file is locked (either using "share" access or with byte-range file locking) and cannot be accessed by other applications" - a feature that dates back to legacy OS's, and may compromise some operations on Windows such as the simple setup of a series of applications.