# Unable to replace file within a folder - File being using by another process

Tags: powershell

When I try to over write an existing file that exists in a folder I get an error saying

> file is being used by another process

Does anybody know how I can override this. I have tried the following, but no luck:

```
Copy-Item $backupDirectoryPathAndFolderName "C:\Program Files\TESTFOLDER" -Recurse -Container -Force
```

Comment: I guess you can not, unless you close the process which is consuming the file. Also, what is the value of $backupDirectoryPathAndFolderName is it possible that you are copying and writing to the same folder ?

Comment: Did you try to find what use the file and stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force close files that are in use when the script runs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180361/force-close-files-that-are-in-use-when-the-script-runs)

Answer (score 0):

If a file is open for writing, your only option is to release the lock.  If the file is open remotely (use **net file** or **openfiles** to identify), you can close down the remote file session.  If, however, it's in use by a local process, you'll need to use **openfiles** with global list enabled or something like **handle.exe** from SysInternals.  Even then, you'll only identify the owning process.  How you convince that process to close the handle is another problem altogether... unless you choose to kill the process, that is.